# Vim script not loaded?

Tags: vim

When I work with some Python files, and run `:set filetype?` in Vim, I get `filetype=python`, so the file is recognized correctly as Python code.

I've downloaded this plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1494
and put it in ftplugin folder, but its f/F keys bindings are not working, and running its `:call ReFold()` gives `E117: Unknown Function` indicating that the plugin hasn't been loaded.

Any troubleshooting tips on how to load the plugin?

Comment: Simple question, but you did reload `vim` right? Other than that it's difficult to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I completely closed the program and re-lunched it several times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing this part at the top of the script:

```
if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
    finish
endif
let b:did_ftplugin = 1
```

And possibly moving the script to `after/ftplugin` directory ([:help after-directory](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#after-directory)).

I think you have another python specific plugin that comes first at `'runtimepath'` and defines `b:did_ftplugin`, which is OK, but this python script (`python_editing.vim`) shouldn't check for and define `b:did_ftplugin` since it doesn't implement the functionality of original plugin, it just extends it.

So the script is loaded, but does nothing. By running `:script` command without arguments one can check if some script is loaded at all.

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks a lot. Out of curiosity, what is this after/ftplugin directory? I don't have such a thing? Should I create it myself?

Comment: Don't create it if the plugin already works. AFAIK `after` directory contains configuration subtree (like `/usr/local` for `/usr`). And all that is inside `after` directory is loaded "after" all other things, thus some options and settings could be overwritten when almost everything is loaded. I couldn't find its description in the documentation right now, will update answer when I find it.

Comment: I didn't find more in the documentation about 'after` directory, so just added a link to the only (and a very brief) description of it.